# How to combine aggregations from grouping

Tags: system.reactive

I have a tail implemetation that pushes new lines from a text file to a `Subject`. The file has the following data:

```
source1, 1
source2, 3
source1, 2
source1, 1
source3, 10
```

I'm trying the create a view of latest aggregations, let's say running sum, by source.

After first line:

`source1, 1`

After second line:

```
source1, 1
source2, 3
```

After third line:

```
source1, 3
source2, 3
```

After forth line:

```
source1, 4
source2, 3
```

After last line:

After forth line:

```
source1, 4
source2, 3
source3, 10
```

This is what I have got so far (in LinqPad):

```
var source = Observable.Generate<int,Measurment>(0,
    current => current <= 10,
    current => current + 1,
    current => current % 3 == 0
        ? new Measurment { Source = "Source1", Value = current }
        : current != 10
            ? new Measurment { Source = "Source2", Value = current }
            : new Measurment { Source = "Source3", Value = current }
);
var grouped = source
.GroupBy(m => m.Source)
.Select(g =>g.Scan((acc,current) =>
    new Measurment { Source = acc.Source, Value = acc.Value + current.Value }));

grouped.Dump();

}
struct Measurment
{
    public string Source;
    public int Value;
```

I get `IObservable<IObservable<Measurment>>`. The inner IObservable have the correctly aggregated values. Now I need to combine the streams and push out a list of Measurments on change in any of the Observables, Any suggestion how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similarly to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21596014/337065) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18834468/337065), there is an [Rxx](http://rxx.codeplex.com/) overload to `CombineLatest` that transforms an `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` to an `IObservable<IList<T>>` which should do what you want. I think that this function should really be in the main Rx library as it's very useful.

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I needed. I have looked at CombineLatest in the core package, but none of the oveerloads took `IObservable<IObservable<Measurment>>`.

I could not find NuGet package of Rxx for Rx 2.x, so I just copied this extesion method. Is there a build of Rxx for Rx 2.xxx?