# Adding to Previously Merged Observable

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to push a new observable into a previously merged stream like so.

```
var state = Observable.merge(
  init,
  increase
).scan((state, changeFn) => changeFn(state), initialState);

let derp = interval(1000).map(() => state => Object.assign({}, state, {count: state.count + 1000}));
state.merge(derp);
```

In the above example, derp is not affecting the value of the internal state; however, if I do the following, it works.

```
var state = Observable.merge(
  init,
  increase,
  derp
).scan((state, changeFn) => changeFn(state), initialState);
```

Is there a way to "push" to a previously merged set of observables after the fact? I'm dynamically creating some DOM elements, and I need to incorporate their click actions into my existing stream.

Comment: This answer may provide some suggestions:https://stackoverflow.com/a/52682130/1647604 It basically creates its own `Subject<Obserable<string>>` and uses `.next` to add more Observables.

Comment: Thank you, the `.next` function was what I needed. Partial example below for anyone that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

The next function is what I was looking for. In case anyone has a similar question, here's a small example of what I landed on.

```
const eventStream = new Subject();

const emitter = eventStream.pipe(
    scan((acc, changeFn) => changeFn(acc), nextChat(initialState)),
    delay(850) // make it feel like it's doing something
);

function createElement(container) {
    const newEl = document.createElement('span');
    fromEvent(newEl, 'click')
        .subscribe(() =>
                   {
                       const compFn = ((state) => returnNewState(state));
                       // eventStream passes state to compFn
                       eventStream.next(compFn);
                   });
    container.appendChild(newEl);
}

const view = emitter.subscribe(state => nextState(state));
```